# Using an external database while running pipeline in GitLab

Tags: gitlab-ci

First of all I am new to CI and GitLab so I may say something that doesn't really make sense. If it happens I apologise and please ask for more details/info.

I have a project (Laravel) which is hosted on GitLab and I am using their CI to run the tests. At the moment, my tests do not make use of any database and everything works fine.

I am now in the situation where I need to do some testing involving data. The problem I am facing is that I have three databases: one is the one managed by my application and two are legacy databases.

The one managed by the application is recreated every time the pipeline runs, it's disposable (for the tests) and I use factories for the data. So, no issues here.

The other two however are legacy, as I said, and I don't have any control over them, apart from being able to read the data.

My test, well some of them, needs data from those databases, but I don't know how to write the gitlab-ci YAML file to use the databases hosted on another server (the UAT server).

I hope someone can help.

Comment: But what exactly is the problem? You just point your tests to the database and it uses it. So is it more about how to setup a secure connection? Maybe how to connect to a database running on premises in your local network? How to dump the data from legacy databases and recreate them in CI?

Comment: Pointing to the databases requires having username and password in the YAML file, which I don't like for security reasons (they would be in clear). I would consider it if I could restrict access somehow (i do it already based in IP address for my website), but I cannot think of a way to achieve it for CI.


Recreating the databases every time seems expensive and I would need to store the dump somewhere which, again, I don't like for security reasons.

Comment: The first one can be solved with https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#secret-variables , maybe a VPN to set up a secure connection. Or maybe just setting up a dedicated runner on the same LAN as the legacy databases. But it seems your problem is more about your concerns with security rather that CI configuration.

Comment: There is definitely an element of security, you're right, and I have to keep that in mind. Maybe I could the runner to connect to the databases using public/private keys, so I can grant access to a user from localhost. Do you think it would work?

Comment: Well, I haven't tested ssh tunnels in Gitlab CI myself but that should work. Try it and let me now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question after an exchange with @jakub-kania and some more research.

What I ended up doing is create an ssh tunnel between the gitlab runner and the server hosting the DB, and use GitLab secret variables to store the username and password for the DB.

So, this is what you need to do.

1. create a private/public key pair. It doesn't matter where as you're going to copy them in different places.
2. create a new user on the server hosting the DB. This is not strictly necessary, you could use an existing user, but it makes it easier to secure (you can create it with the `--disabled-password` and `--disabled-login` options).
3. add the public key you created earlier to the `authorized_keys` file of the new user.
4. follow the instruction on this page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor.
5. create two secret variables for the DB username and password, called `BLOG_DB_USERNAME` and `BLOG_DB_PASSWORD`.
6. configure your application to use the username and password stored in the secret variable. In my case, I have a Laravel app, so I added the following to the script section of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

   ```
   - echo >> .env
   - echo "BLOG_DB_USERNAME=$BLOG_DB_USERNAME" >> .env
   - echo "BLOG_DB_PASSWORD=$BLOG_DB_PASSWORD" >> .env
   ```

I hope this helps someone else too.